# File reading/writing speed

Tags: c#, performance, file

In NTFS, is the reading/writing speed of a file(with a known path) influenced by the number of files in the same folder?

es:

```
var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(aKnownPath);
```

Comment: I do not see why this should be downvoted and closed. This is a legitimate programming question and an answer can be provided/experiments can be done to prove/disprove the hypothesis.

Comment: Share with us the data you gathered while investigating this issue.

Comment: @Marek: I think it'd be reasonable to question whether this is better suited to StackOverflow or SuperUser. There's nothing programming-specific about the question; it's more related to the OS/file system. It's certainly not a C# question! (That said, I'm not the close voter, but I can understand why people might.)

Comment: Reading/Write time is independent of number of files in a folder.  But the time to Open the file is dependent on the number of files in the folder.  When a file is opened it must find the folder on the disk.  Then check each file in the folder for the filename.  The folder directory is sequential so the average time to find the file is N/2 where N is the number of files in the folder.

Comment: @jdweng that should have been an answer, feel free to copy paste into the answer box below

Comment: i dont know how c# file api interact with file system at os level, its an unexplored world to me. @jsweng, thx for the answer, in my case, i dont need to access all files, i have all paths registered in a db.

Comment: @jdweng, but what do you mean by "open"? showing it in explorer?

Comment: Not exactly.  An open actually consists of two parts.  First you must locate the file, then actually open the file.  When using an explorer you already have performed the "locate" and just need to do the open.  When I was referring to open a meant using the full filename like c:\temp\test.txt.  The temp folder could have hundreds of file so if there are 500 files in the temp folder it would take 500/2 test before finding the file name.  The time to actually open is independent of the number of files in folder.

Answer (score 0):

*Locating* a file takes more time per each file in the directory.

*Reading* from an opened file is constant.